# Default to Laptop display (Edubuntu 12.04.2)

Tags: 12.04, edubuntu

In Edubuntu 12.04.2, is there a way to have the system sense the attached monitor (I'm running this on a desktop - Dell Optiplex 740 - and not a laptop.) Every 12.04.2 install I've done defaults to a 640x480 (Laptop) screen

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary driver ?
-> Under System Settings / Additional Drivers

Comment: Were I aware of what drivers I needed, I would do that, yet during the install, the LiveCD's desktop was properly displayed in a resolution suitable to the monitor and synched apparently to the resident video controller. I've done several installs of this Ubuntu 12.04.2 (and Edubuntu 12.04.2) and they both come up defaulting to a Laptop (640x480) Display setting, with no others being an option. I guess this should be posted as an error to the distro.